Container overflowed in the widget
I am trying right now to do this on my home page app but I get something messed up in the code in the container under Location. Here it's what I am trying to achieve 
And here it's what I get by now : 
Any idea what I should change to the code to make it like in the first picture? I commented the Subscribe Button because I get more pixels overflowed
Stack(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    spreadRadius: 5,
                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                  )
                                ]),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.2,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                              child: Column(children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0),
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 50,
                                    backgroundImage: ((snaps.data?.data()
                                                as Map)['avatarUrl'] ==
                                            'default')
                                        ? const NetworkImage(
                                            "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"

                                            //  activity.imageUrl,

                                            )
                                        : NetworkImage((snaps.data?.data()
                                            as Map)['avatarUrl']),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 170.0,
                                  // width: double.infinity,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.5,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 120.0,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                (snaps.data?.data()
                                                    as Map)['name'],
                                                // activity.name,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                ),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                maxLines: 2,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.5,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 120.0,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                (snaps.data?.data()
                                                    as Map)['address'],
                                                // activity.name,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                ),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                maxLines: 2,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          (snapshot2.data?.data()
                                              as Map)['category'],
                                          // activity.type,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 20,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            height: 80,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.75,
                                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                                              shadows: [
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                                  blurRadius: 10,
                                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            child: const Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceEvenly,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Subscribers',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text('356',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey)),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  VerticalDivider(
                                                    indent: 8,
                                                    endIndent: 8,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Programs',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text('8',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey)),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  VerticalDivider(
                                                    indent: 8,
                                                    endIndent: 8,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Ratings',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text('5.0',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey)),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ])),
                                        // const SizedBox(
                                        //   height: 10,
                                        // ),
                                        // SizedBox(
                                        //   width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        //           .size
                                        //           .width /
                                        //       2.5,
                                        //   child: ElevatedButton(
                                        //     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        //       backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                        //       padding:
                                        //           const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        //               vertical: 16),
                                        //       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        //         borderRadius:
                                        //             BorderRadius.circular(32),
                                        //       ),
                                        //     ),
                                        //     onPressed: () {},
                                        //     child: const Text(
                                        //       "SUBSCRIBE",
                                        //       style: TextStyle(
                                        //           color: Colors.white,
                                        //           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        //     ),
                                        //   ),
                                        // ),
                                      ]),
                                )
                              ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          right: 35,
                          child: TextButton(
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                              disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'TOP 5',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),


adjust the Container height and ensure proper handling of text widgets to fit within their allotted space.

Here is your code with some adjustments:
Stack(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3),
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage((snaps.data?.data() as Map)['avatarUrl'] ?? "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
              child: Text(
                (snaps.data?.data() as Map)['name'],
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
              child: Text(
                (snaps.data?.data() as Map)['address'],
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              (snapshot2.data?.data() as Map)['category'],
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                shadows: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Subscribers',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '356',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  VerticalDivider(indent: 8, endIndent: 8),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Programs',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '8',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  VerticalDivider(indent: 8, endIndent: 8),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Ratings',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '5.0',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 35,
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: null,
        child: Text(
          'TOP 5',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

